# Links not working while applying slideToggle

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

while applying slideToggle function the links are not working. below is the link for my demo site.

http://codezigns.com/teyseer_laboratory/htm/toggle.html

my script is

```
$(".nav li > a").click(function(e) {
        $(this).parent().siblings().find('ul').slideUp(500);
        $(this).next('ul').stop().slideToggle(300);
        return false;
    });
```

and also include

```
$(".trigger").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(".main-nav > ul").slideToggle(300);
    });
```

Link is applied in parent item "Tutorial" and child item "Photoshop".

Answer (score 0):

Remove `return false;` from your `a` `click` event. It is preventing redirection.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because you are returning false on `a` click event, you should exclude the links from returning false, you should add a class to the real links and exclude them of your function:

HTML

```
<nav class="nav">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Tutorials</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a class="reallink" href="https://www.google.co.in/">Photoshop</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Illustrator</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Web Design</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Articles</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Inspiration</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

JS:

```
   $(".nav li > a:not(.reallink)").click(function(e) {
        $(this).parent().siblings().find('ul').slideUp(500);
        $(this).next('ul').stop().slideToggle(300);
        return false;
    });
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are returning `false` for each `a` click. Try like following. Hope this will help you.

```
$(".nav li > a").click(function (e) {
    if(this.href.indexOf('#') > -1) {
        $(this).parent().siblings().find('ul').slideUp(500);
        $(this).next('ul').stop().slideToggle(300);
        return false;
    }
});
```